# PGFplots turn on marks locally after global turn off

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I turned off the marks in the preamble of my document with `\pgfplotsset{no markers}`. Now I want one particular plot to show markers, while I'd like to keep the global `no markers` for the rest of the document.
Here's what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{no markers}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates { (1,1) (2,2) (3,2) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[mark options={*}]% does not work
    \addplot coordinates { (1,1) (2,2) (3,2) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[mark options={*}]% does not work
    \addplot[mark=*] coordinates { (1,1) (2,2) (3,2) };% does not work, but strangely changes line color to black?
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is this:
[image: Left side: marks are off, as wanted; Middle: marks are not on again - unwanted; Right side: lines turn black - strange and unwanted]

How do I turn on the marks for a specific plot only while leaving them off for the rest of the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `no markers` is defined as

```
/pgfplots/no markers/.style={/pgfplots/every axis plot post/.append style={mark=none}},
```

meaning it hooks at the end of the plots. So you may want to hook even later, e.g.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{no markers}
\pgfplotsset{but I really want a mark/.style={/pgfplots/every axis plot
post/.append style={mark=#1}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates { (1,1) (2,2) (3,2) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[but I really want a mark={*}]% works
    \addplot coordinates { (1,1) (2,2) (3,2) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @schrödingers-cat. That is doing the job for me.
I also verified, that the marks are off again afterwards for the following plots.